# Find a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have some general and specific questions about field extensions.

Firstly, is it always the case that $ \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, \alpha_2) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)(\alpha_2) $?

Hence, a solution to find a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ is to write an element as $\alpha + \beta \sqrt[3]{3}$ with $ \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}$). So

$$ \alpha + \beta \sqrt[3]{3} = (a + b\sqrt[3]{2}) + (c + d\sqrt[3]{2})\sqrt[3]{3} = a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{3} + d\sqrt[3]{6}, \ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$$

and a basis is then $ \{1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[3]{6} \}$. Is this correct, and is this approach the way to go for such problems?

Secondly, how does one check that $ [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}): \mathbb{Q} ] = 4 $? I realise that

$$ \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}), \quad \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}), \quad \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}), \quad \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$$

To calculate $ [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}): \mathbb{Q} ]$ I need to know what $ [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} ]$ is. How do I know what that is?

Thanks!

Comment: How would you write $\sqrt[3]{2}^2$ as a linear combination of $1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[3]{6}$ with rational coeffitients?

Comment: "Secondly, how does one check that $ [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}): \mathbb{Q} ] = 4 $?" You don't because that's false.

Comment: We have $ [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} ]=3$ by the duplicate. So $ [ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}): \mathbb{Q} ]=9$.